# How do you send http_referrer data when cflocation removes it

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, http-referer, cflocation

I have a website that logs clickthroughs to client sites.  It's how I track meaningful activity on ColdFusion.

The problem is the after I write to the database, I use CFLocation.  It sends a blank http_referrer.  This means that the receiving website does not know the click came from my site.

I am assuming that I need some sort of javascript code that will allow for the http_referrer to be preserved while somehow writing the click date/time info to the database through ColdFusion.

Comment: Can you put the database write into a different thread?  There is a tag for that.  Also, javascript window.location and html meta refresh are simple alternatives to cflocation.

Comment: Do you have a favorite how-to site for javascript window.location?